# How can I display the time of a http request in android?

Tags: android

Hey guys so I'm suppose to make a Post request to a server and display the time of how long it took to make that request. I successfully made the post request to the server the only thing is how do I get the time that the request took to display please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by saving the timestamps.
Get the first one right before you start your request:

```
long startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The second timestamp, lets call it endTime, will then be set in the onSuccess() of your request.

Then you can get the duration oft the request by

```
Long duration = endTime - startTime;
```

Comment: Can you please explain in little more detail

Comment: @RonnyPerez What exactly to you wat to be explained in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

Using timer class of java you can calculate total time of processing of a http request.just start timer when you are in background method of async task and stop the timer when you got the result.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any native method to get time of this process but we can measure  this time to follow these step

```
 1. get the currenttimemillis in onPreExecute() of async task 
 2. and also get currenttimemillis in  onPostExecute() of async task
```

then just get difference of both u can get the time of request

use timer class also but i think in async task may be getting some prob with timer thread.